# Map Memtest86 memory error report to actual DIMM

Tags: memory, motherboard, memtest

Given: motherboard Intel DBS1200BTL, which started to exhibit hardware problems, most probably RAM-related.

After booting MemTest86 v7.5 (from USB stick), I receive ECC error reports, but I can't figure out how to map them to actual memory slot/DIMM.

Example of report lines:

```
2018-05-11 00:13:21 - ERRSTS=0001
2018-05-11 00:13:21 - [Channel 0] ERRLOG0=03040001, ERRLOG1=033856F7
2018-05-11 00:13:21 - [MEM ERROR - ECC] Test: 13, (Col,Row,Rank,Bank): 338,56F7,0,0), ECC Corrected: yes, Syndrome: 0004, Channel/Slot: 0/0
2018-05-11 00:13:21 - [Channel 1] ERRLOG0=00000000, ERRLOG1=00000000
```

Running decode-dimms provides me with this info:

```
---=== Memory Characteristics ===---
Maximum module speed                             1333 MHz (PC3-10600)
Size                                             4096 MB
Banks x Rows x Columns x Bits                    8 x 15 x 10 x 64
Ranks                                            2
SDRAM Device Width                               8 bits
Bus Width Extension                              8 bits
```

Looks like I have to run the "Hammer" tests sequence (Test 13 in MemTest86 list) 16 times, for every single DIMM inserted into every slot, to find what exactly fails (motherboard slots and/or DIMMs). However, it would be nicer to avoid that (since it's extremely time-consuming) and just decode the (col, row,rank,bank) into system memory address.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's the RAM and not the CPU/Motherboard?  Do you have a spare motherboard to throw all of the RAM into? Otherwise I would test half the RAM. If it's good, then you know it's in the other half. Test half of the RAM that has the known bad one, then halve it again etc. to narrow down which one it is.

Comment: Either RAM, or motherboard. Problem is there are no other motherboards compatible with this given RAM. Also, I can only insert 2 or 4 DIMMs (cannot insert single one). So now I test the DIMM/slots combinations, in absence of better ideas.